# Pushing array of objects to data layer pushes string of '[object Object]' instead

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager

Whenever I try to push an array of objects to the data layer, it gets serialized as an array of '[object Object]' instead of the actual objects.

When someone lands on the 'products' page, I want to push all the products that the customer can see as 'impressions' to the data layer. The amount of products can vary so I'm looping through all the products and adding them to an array that is pushed to the data layer. I have also tried just pushing one of the objects, and that is also pushed as '[object Object]'.

This is the object I'm trying to push an array of:

```
class Impression {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  list: string;
  brand: string;
  category: string;
  variant: string;
  position: number;
  price: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use javascript objects rather than a class to create your own object.

Read up about JSON and JavaScript objects and you will be able to figure it out.